# Castle Windsor Interceptors - get Target already in the ctor

Tags: castle-windsor

When I'm using interceptors in Castle Windsor, I can get access to the invocation target whenever a function is called (invocation parameter of type IInvocation).

Is it possible to get the target of the interceptor already in the constructor of this interceptor, so that I can write code like follows:

```
public class MyInterceptor: IInterceptor
{
   public MyInterceptor(ITargetOfInterception target, ILogger logger) 
   { 
       logger.Log("Interceptor created for target type: " + target.GetType() );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get access to the target in the constructor but you can achieve what you're after by implementing `IOnBehalfAware` ([see doco here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/aa9b8b353ee2e533d586495eec254e216f800c09/docs/interceptors.md#ionbehalfaware-interface))

```
public void SetInterceptedComponentModel(ComponentModel target)
{
    logger.Log("Interceptor created for target: " + target.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for. Is it also possible to get a reference to the InvocationTarget on this place? (same as IInvocation.InvocationTarget in the Intercept-method?). I can not find the equivalent property in the ComponentModel.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your instance already...

```
container.Register(Component.For<IInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<Logger>().Named("myinterceptor"));
```

Then each class you will decorate with an attribute with your interceptor.

```
[Interceptor("myinterceptor")]
public class Logger : IInterceptor 
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation) {
        Console.WriteLine(">> type in <<");
        invocation.Proceed();
        Console.WriteLine(">> type out <<");
    }    
}
```

If you implement interceptor you will be able to know which type is resolved because you have defined such cross cutting concerns to be addressed by the interceptor.

I think you are wanting to have your interceptor know all types that require a contract with the interceptor instead of all types that are bound to the interceptors' instructions. I hope this helps!!

EDIT: This is how I use Unity to Logger:

```
    Public Class LoggingInterceptionBehavior
        Implements IInterceptionBehavior
        Public Function Invoke(input As IMethodInvocation, getNext As GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate) As IMethodReturn Implements IInterceptionBehavior.Invoke
            ' Before invoking the method on the original target. 
            Dim icp As ClaimsPrincipal = TryCast(Thread.CurrentPrincipal, ClaimsPrincipal)

            ' Access IClaimsIdentity which contains claims
            Dim claimsIdentity As ClaimsIdentity = DirectCast(icp.Identity, ClaimsIdentity)
            Dim param = GetParam(input)

            If claimsIdentity IsNot Nothing Then
                If param IsNot Nothing Then
                    WriteLog([String].Format("{0} is invoking method {1} at {2} with a parameter of {3}", claimsIdentity.Name, input.MethodBase, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), param))
                Else
                    WriteLog([String].Format("{0} is invoking method {1} at {2} without a parameter", claimsIdentity.Name, input.MethodBase, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()))
                End If

            Else
                'no claim
                WriteLog([String].Format("NO CLAIM Invoking method {0} at {1} with a parameter of {2}", input.MethodBase, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(), param))
            End If

            ' Invoke the next behavior in the chain.
            Dim result = getNext()(input, getNext)

            ' After invoking the method on the original target.
            If result.Exception IsNot Nothing Then
                WriteCriticalLog([String].Format("Method {0} threw exception {1} at {2}", input.MethodBase, result.Exception.Message, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()))
            Else
                WriteLog([String].Format("Method {0} returned {1} at {2}", input.MethodBase, result.ReturnValue, DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()))
            End If

            Return result
        End Function

End Class
```

How I register them :

```
    container.RegisterType(Of IXXXService, XXXService)(New Interceptor(Of InterfaceInterceptor)(),
                                                                 New InterceptionBehavior(Of LoggingInterceptionBehavior))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have one implementation of an interceptor (e.g. a logging interceptor) for different kind of classes to be intercepted. And I want to detected, if such a class is resolved and log this. And not first when the first method is called.

Comment: 2 answers. 1: I advise moving to Unity to get these kinds of features. To do so requires a bit of learning curve to do so. 2: documentation is a bit sparse - https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/debugger-views.md, but it should lead you down how to debug your container.

Comment: 1. moving to unity is not an option for me, I like Castle Windsor very much ;-). 2: I do not want to debug my container. I just want to use interceptors and get the access to the target of invocation already in the constructor (same as it is implemented for the intercept method).

Comment: This is as far as I could find answers, aside from executing code to find out the benefit of knowing in your ctor. https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/interceptors.md

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know why you need it, I can think of 2 possible solutions for this.

First, you can hook on container.ComponentRegistered event ([or some other event of your choosing](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/container-events.md)), and inspect the handler to see the interceptors.

Second, you can use some static hash table in the interceptor, and log when a "new" target is detected on Intercept.

Probably the first solution is what you want.